# Add files to zip and download zip using php

Tags: php, zip

I have a web service that is requesting for data. The data received is being stored in the variable `$response`.

After that, i am creating files to store the data.

Then i am trying to add these files to a zip and afterwards download that zip. I have consulted various questions and answers similar to mine but i still cannot solve my problem. Note that i have the zip library installed.

Below is my php script:

```
// Load zip library
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//Zip name
$zip_name = "data.zip";

if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){ 
    // Opening zip file to load files
    $error = "ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
else{
    echo "zip creation successful";
}

function myFunc(){
    //Some codes
     global $zip;

     $myfile = fopen($filepath, "w");

     fwrite($myfile, $response);
     fclose($myfile);

     echo "test1";
     try {
        //add file to zip
        $zip->addFile($myfile);
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
     echo "test2";
}

$zip->close();

//Some codes    

if(file_exists($zip_name)){
    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($zip_name);

    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($zip_name);
}
```

After running the above script, **test1** is being displayed and not **test2**. I think that the problem lies in this line `$zip->addFile($myfile);`.

From previous posts, i could notice that the function `addFile` takes 2 parameters. How can i edit my code for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2. parameter of addFile() is optional, according to the docs. Maybe it throws an Exception and you dont notice it? Add your code in a  Try/Catch block and catch the exception (if any) to debug the problem.

Comment: `addFile` takes a file path, you're giving it a (closed) file handle. Does it work if you use `$zip->addFile($filepath);` instead?

Comment: @paskl I edited my question to add a try/catch block. It does not even show the exception message.

Comment: @rickdenhaan It does not work at all. I am not sure what path to give it since i have created a file with my data in it, i just need to add it to the zip and download it afterwards.

Comment: Give it the same path you give to `fopen()` when you write the results to the text file. Alternatively, skip the whole file creation and use `$zip->addFileFromString("data.txt", $response);`

Comment: @rickdenhaan I commented all the file creation process and used this line `$zip->addFileFromString("data.txt", $response);` instead of  `$zip->addFile($myfile);`. Still nothing.

Comment: Ok, looking at this a little more closely.... is the global `$zip` imported into your `myFunc()` function's scope (by calling `global $zip;`)? Or are you getting an "Undefined variable: zip" notice followed by a "Call to a member function addFileFromString() on a non-object" fatal error? Possibly in your server's log file, if you don't have error reporting set correctly.

Comment: I did not import it, since it is global. Normally it should be recognised inside `myFunc()` .  I have checked the logs, indeed this is what i am getting:  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addFileFromString() on null in /var/www/html/Website/download2.php on line 74,`

Comment: No, variables from the global scope are, by default, **not** available inside a function so you *have* to import it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190175/discussion-between-bhavish030-and-rickdenhaan).

Comment: Hi @rickdenhaan Have you been able to find a work around for me please?

Comment: Sorry dude, different timezones and real life intervened (I'm not on here 24/7). Check the chat for some questions and things you can try.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Am very sorry. Actually in chat, i don't get any notifications when you reply. I thought i might be the same for you. That's why i added a comment. Anyways i made the changes you mentioned in the chat, and i worked perfectly as expected. Many thanks for your help. Much appreciated :D